# Unsure how to set correct input shape for neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to craft a neural network based on two research papers, but after cobbling something together using some examples online it runs but seems to be stuck at 57% accuracy no matter what I try to modify. I am quite sure there is something wrong with how I shaped the input to the model, but I don't understand enough to see why it's wrong and how to fix it.

The first paper (Quantitative Trading on Stock Market Based on Deep Reinforcement Learning by Jia WU, Chen WANG, Lidong XIONG, Hongyong SUN) states:

The LSTMbased agent is composed of an input layer, 5-layer LSTM
with 31 hidden units on each layer, a dense layer and a soft-max layer. The update rate of the baseline function b is 0.8. Weights of the agent are initialized uniformly between -0.2 and 0.2. The neural network of the agent is trained with Adam optimizer [30] with a learning rate of
0.001.

The second paper (Effects of Activation Functions and Optimizers on Stock Price Prediction using LSTM Recurrent Networks by Masud Rana, Md. Mohsin Uddin, Md. Mohaimnul Hoque) states:

The result is shown that linear activation function and adamax optimizer and, tanh activation function and adam optimizer make almost the same prediction that is better than other activation functions and optimizers’ prediction.

I want to try and implement both models, or one that takes inspiration from both (I couldn't really understand what the model in the second paper looks like so I focused on the activation functions).

My data set is a csv with a date, some daily Forex data including technical indicators and world bank data, and a Target Column that is 1 if the closing price 30 days from that day is higher than that day's closing price.

My code is:
`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, InputLayer
from keras.optimizers import Adam, Adamax
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
# Load the data into a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:...categorical.csv', index_col=False)
df.index = df.pop('Date')
RowNum = len(df.axes[0])
ColNum = len(df.axes[1])-1 #Number of columns - 1 for target

X = df.iloc[:, :ColNum].values
y = df.iloc[:, ColNum].values
X = np.reshape(X, (RowNum, ColNum, 1))
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', min_delta=1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(ColNum, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(31, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(ColNum, 1), activation='tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(31, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(31, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(31, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(31, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.2, maxval=0.2)))
# Compile the model

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model to the data
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=90, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[es])
```

`

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: You should try to use `sigmoid` for the last layer's activation and `binary_crossentropy` as a loss function. `tanh` produce negative values, while `categorical_crossentropy` use logarithm and that may cause a problem.

Comment: `I am trying to craft a neural network based on two research papers, but after cobbling something together using some examples online it runs but seems to be stuck at 57% accuracy no matter what I try to modify.` What's the accuracy rate you're expecting? What accuracy did the authors get? In general, I would expect forex prices to be almost a pure random walk.

Comment: @NickODell the second paper boasted a RMSE of about 0.01 whereas the first paper showed a positive average profit